# "What do you want to be when you grow up?"

Tags: tenses

The usual question and answer seem to be of the form

> What do you want to be when you **grow up**?
>
> I want to be a singer when I **grow up**.

Should it not be

> What do you want to be when you **have grown up**?
>
> I want to be a singer when I **have grown up**.

Here we have interpreted *grow up* as the process at whose end one becomes a singer. Should the first pair be considered correct simply because of its accepted usage, or is there an alternative explanation for this?

Comment: Also used is "are grown up" ("'re ...").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, because a present tense is normal for an achievement in the future:

> When I am ready
>
> When I get tired
>
> When I reach London

In all of these a perfect is possible ("When I have reached London" etc), but not required.

"Grow up" can be a process, but in "When you grow up" it is, at least notionally, an achievement (i.e. end of a process).

Comment: How about 'What do you want to visit when you travel to London'?

Comment: "Grow up" can be a process, but in "When you grow up" it is, at least notionally, an achievement (i.e. end of a process).